# Is there a way to define maths in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am working on a project using nextjs and my screen is showing maths is not defined, how do i solve it

I tried importing but it didn't work

Comment: What’s “maths”? Do you mean “mathjs”? Is it in your package file?

Comment: Do i have to install it?

Comment: If you want to use it, yes, you'd need to actually have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reinstalling mathjs and ensure that you're importing it properly.

```
import { math } from 'mathjs';
```

Also make sure there are no typos. Its "math.evaluate" and not "maths.evaluate"

```
const result = math.evaluate('2 + 3');
```

For different usecase:
If you want to render math expressions instead, try using "Ketex".

Here is an example on how to use it:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import 'katex/dist/katex.min.css';
import katex from 'katex';

const options = {
  throwOnError: false,
  errorColor: '#cc0000',
};

function MathComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    katex.render('c = \\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}', document.getElementById('math'), options);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="math"></div>
  );
}

export default MathComponent;
```

You can visit their website to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a typo in the variable or function name or an incorrect import statement.

However, you can use the mathjs library to perform mathematical operations in your Next.js project.

1. Install the mathjs library using a package manager such as npm or yarn.

> run `npm install mathjs` or `yarn add mathjs`

2. Import the mathjs library

> `import * as math from 'mathjs'`